# Anchors not going to where they're supposed to

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble with anchors on my page. When I am on the page, and click on an anchor in the dropdown menu "Our services" it goes to the right place. But when I click on the logo "NCK", and then click on one of the anchors in the dropdown menu, it doesn't go to the right place? How can that be?

[Link to page, to see HTML and error](http://www.clauson-kaas.com/rwd)

Comment: It seems to working.

Comment: Maybe hard refresh your page or something? Works for me. "it doesn't go to the right place?" Where does it go?

Answer (score 0):

change link "/rwd/Our-services#projectmanagement" to "#projectmanagement" (doing this for all other links also)
OR
simply remove default event of all links of dropdown which has problem with this code

```
$('#yourdropdownlink1_ID').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

use above code for all dropdown links